# In Android, How to stream live video from Live Stream?

Tags: android

Any suggestion for live stream for android.

In my app i need to stream live video from Live Stream.. 
Is there any api or example to do it? If so, please provide it.

I need as like this...

http://www.livestream.com/aplive?utm_source=website-home&utm_medium=promo-header&utm_campaign=aplive

Thanks,
jana.

Comment: Hi Jana did u find a way for live stream in android? I am as well looking for the same as the native android MediaPlayer doesnt MPEG4 format.

Comment: No, i didnt get apt solution yet..

Answer (score 0):

There's information about the API here http://www.livestream.com/platform/developer but it's mostly for flash development.

you may be able to make it work with android.